# React Native Expo Animated _reactNative.Animated.interpolate is not a funciton

Tags: react-native, animation, hook, expo

im getting this error when try to animate a header of a view. 
TypeError: _reactNative.Animated.interpolate is not a function

i tryed to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPx8IlfYQ-c with react-native HOOKS, I also tryed to use react-native-reanimated without success. I am using expo sdk 35.0.0 wiht react 16.8.3  and try with react-native-reanaimeted: 1.7.0 but in this example i imported directly from react-native with import {Animated} from 'react-native'

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Image,
    FlatList,
    Animated,
    TouchableWithoutFeedback
} from 'react-native';

const HEADER__HEIGHT = 70
const KitCardItem = ({student, onPressCard, insertItemDialogVisible, setinsertItemDialogVisible}) => {
    const {date, items} = student || {};
    const [itemsVisible, setItemsVisible] = useState(true)

    const scrollY = new Animated.Value(0)
    const headerY = Animated.interpolate(scrollY, {
        inputRange: [0, HEADER__HEIGHT],
        outputRange: [0, -HEADER__HEIGHT],

    })  

    return (    
        <View style={{height: '100%', justifyContent: 'center'}}>   
            <Animated.View style={{
                height: HEADER__HEIGHT,
                transform: [{translateY: headerY}]
            }}>
                <View
                    style={{width: '100%', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                    <Text style={{fontWeight: '700', fontSize: 16, fontcolor: titleColor}}>{getDateTitle()}</Text>
                </View>
            </Animated.View>


            <View style={{flex: 1,}}>
                <Animated.FlatList
                    scrollEventThrottle={16}
                    onScroll={ Animated.event([
                        {
                            nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: scrollY}}
                        }
                    ])}
                    listKey={(item, index) => item._id}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    vertical
                    style={{flex: 1,}}
                    data={items}
                    renderItem={({item, index}) => renderItem(item, index)}/>

            </View>


            {items.length === 0 &&
            <View style={emptyContainer}>
                <EmptyState

                    message={'Ainda sem notas para esse dia.'}
                />
            </View>                }


        </View>    
    )  
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});


export default KitCardItem
```

Comment: `scrollY.interpolate({inputRange: ... })`

Comment: @giotskhada now i got the error even if i check scrollY 
TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Animated\src\nodes\AnimatedInterpolation.js:294:16 in checkInfiniteRange
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Animated\src\nodes\AnimatedInterpolation.js:49:2 in createInterpolation

Comment: const scrollY = new Animated.Value(0)
    const headerY = scrollY? scrollY.interpolate(scrollY, {
        inputRange: [0, HEADER__HEIGHT],
        outputRange: [0, -HEADER__HEIGHT],

    }) : null

Comment: You have to put `scrollY` in a ref or a state. Otherwise, it will be initialized on every render. `const scrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current`

Comment: still same error @giotskhada 

 const scrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current
    const headerY = scrollY? scrollY.interpolate(scrollY, {
        inputRange: [0, HEADER__HEIGHT],
        outputRange: [0, -HEADER__HEIGHT],

    }) : null

Comment: tried a diferent aproach wihout success to, 

  var scrollY
    var headerY

    useEffect(()=>{
        scrollY = new Animated.Value(0)
        headerY = scrollY? scrollY.interpolate(scrollY, {
            inputRange: [0, HEADER__HEIGHT],
            outputRange: [0, -HEADER__HEIGHT],

        }) : null
    },[scrollY])

TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValue' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

react-native-reanimated changed `Animated.interpolate` to `Animated.interpolateNode`

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as advised in the other answer. Change Animated.interpolate to Animated.interpolateNode. Here is the updated code.

```
const headerY = Animated.interpolateNode(scrollY, {
    inputRange: [0, HEADER__HEIGHT],
    outputRange: [0, -HEADER__HEIGHT],

})
```